# Prove that there is a zero of a derivative $x_0$ such that $|p(x_0)| < \frac{2}{3} |x_0|$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

Let $p(x)$ be $a_5 x^5 + a_4 x^4 + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + x, a_5 \neq 0$, all zeros of $p'$ are from $\mathbb{R}$. I need to prove that there is $x_0$ a zero of a derivative such that $|p(x_0)| < \frac{2}{3} |x_0|$.
$$p'(x) = 5 a_5 x^4 + 4 a_4 x^3 + 3 a_3 x^2 + 2 a_2 x + 1$$
From here I don't know what to do. I've tried assuming the opposite, but it got me nowhere. It's the first time I've come across this type of exercise, how should I approach this?

Comment: Your p'(x) needs a +1 at the end of it (since p(x) has a final term of +x). So there is no $x$ common factor of the p'(x) polynomial

Comment: @JimN Shoot.. Yeah, I will edit the question. Thanks! I am completely lost now tho..

Comment: Yes, I don't see how you can proceed with this information. A general quartic might not have any real roots at all. Are you sure you don't have additional information on these $a_i$ coefficients?

Comment: I see you have added the info that p'(x) has all real roots. You probably should begin with $p'(x)=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment tho.

Consider a simple case (other cases might work or might not, I did not check   : ) ).

Assume the roots are $0 < r_1 < r_2 < r_3 < r_4$ for $p'$, then use $p'(0) = 1$, we must have $p'$ is positive on $(-\infty, r_1)$, otherwise there exists another root for $p'$.

Because $p'$ is a degree 4 polynomial, thus the $\text{sgn}(p') = \text{sgn}(a_5) = 1$ on $(-\infty, r_1)$.

By Rolle's theorem, the roots of $p''$ and $p'''$ are all on the interval $(r_1, r_4)$, therefore the sign of $p'''$ is fixed on $(-\infty, r_1)$ as well, which is $\text{sgn}(p''') = \text{sgn}(a_5) = 1$ again.

This means $p'''$ is positive on $(-\infty, r_1)$ hence $p'$ is convex on $(-\infty, r_1)$.

Now we use Jensen inequality and $p'(0) = 1$,

$$p(r_1) - 0 = \int_{0}^{r_1} p'(t) dt \le \int_{0}^{r_1} \left((1 - \frac{t}{r_1})p'(0) + \frac{t}{r_1} p'(r_1) \right) dt = \frac{1}{2} r_1 < \frac{2}{3} r_1.$$

Comment: Where can I read about the Jensen inequality? I've tried googling it but couldn't find the version you are using.

Comment: Never mind I proved it myself. Thanks for your answer, it does work for other cases too.

Comment: good to know it works for other cases.